# Papers about Electron Spin

Tags: angular-momentum, electrons, quantum-spin, resource-recommendations, history

What are some of the earliest papers about electron spin? Who were the scientists to develop the concept and why?

Comment: what have you uncovered in your own searches on this topic?

Comment: S. Goudsmit and G. Uhlenbeck, Naturwiss. 13, 953 (1925); Nature 117, 264 (1926). https://www.nature.com/articles/117264a0

Comment: @SethWhitsitt thanks

Comment: You may be interested in the book "The Story of Spin" by Sin-itiro Tomonaga (who won the Nobel Prize with Feynman)

Comment: W. Pauli, “Zur Quantenmechanik des magnetischen Elektrons”, Zeitschrift für Physik  43, 601 (1927). I think there should be also an English translation.

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend.

Comment: See this paper and the references therein https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3128